# What we do if the answer contained answer's url get expired?

Tags: discussion

From so many days I am observing that so many questions and answers have existed in Magento stack exchange. But, some answers have the url's get expired. What should we do?

Example : [Extra charge for a payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108884/extra-charge-for-a-payment-method/108890#108890)

If anyone wants the answer to this question, what is the solution?